# Laptop only fan and power nothing else

Tags: boot, laptop, cpu, motherboard, power

I have a Samsung NP300V4A. i5 2nd generation. 4gb ram, nvidia gt520mx. It was all working fine but when I turned it on today morning, I see the power light and hear the fan spinning. Nothing else.  Not even the motherboard screen. 
Please someone help me. I only do one thing unusual. I put lap in sleep instead of shutting it down. Is that a problem?

Comment: @wp78de I have a little issue with the power button. So not sure if it was in contact with the circuit for the 60s. What If the graphics card is dead? Do you why this thing happened to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem a while ago. On power on the screen would stay black, no POST, nothing at all on the display. The hard disk spin up, but no HDD indicator and no boot happend.

To resolve this, unplug the power, remove the battery and then hold the power button for 30 to 60 seconds. Then reattach the power and attempt a boot. This time it should boot. Then just shutdown, put the battery back in. Worked for me, so definitely worth a try. Sometimes the EFI gets messed up, when the computer is not rebooted for a long time (as you wrote you put your computer all the time to just to sleep).

Otherwise, I guess the graphics cards is broken or its maybe something with the display. Tried to attach the notebook to an external display with all your available graphics ports.

Comment: I have a little issue with the power button. So not sure if it was in contact with the circuit for the 60s. What If the graphics card is dead? Do you why this thing happened to you?

Comment: I stopped using my laptop for about a month. Then I turn it on with no sign of life. This brought mine back to life. Most laptops have an onboard graphics cards. This often means you have to exchange the whole motherboard if your GFX is dead. I would consider the graphics card as the weakest part of a laptop nowadays (since we have SSDs).

Comment: I think I have discrete graphics. In my device manager it shows both Intel HD graphics and nvidia. So will i be able to run it on either of them? How much approx to replace gpu?

Comment: what to do if EFI gets messed up? I tries connecting it to two other monitors and a TV. No result. What if the graphics card is broken.?

Comment: Since you have an older laptop model you may have trouble finding spare parts and information on how to repair your device on your own. Replacing the dedicated graphics card would be the first thing to try. But this is not an easy task and often requires an expert.